# What does "the world has brought you down to your knees" mean"

Tags: idiom-meaning

I came across a theme song, [I'll Be There For You](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rembrandts:I'll_Be_There_For_You) of an American TV show, Friends but I don't understand the bolded lyrics.

> You're still in bed at ten and work began at eight
>
> You've burned your breakfast, so far things are going great
>
> Your mother warned you there'd be days like these
>
> But she didn't tell you when **the world has brought you down to your
>   knees** that

When I checked the dictionary, I found that:

(1) [bring·down](https://www.google.com/search?q=bring%20down%20meaning&rlz=1C1ASUT_enMY619MY619&oq=bring%20down%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65l2j69i60.2496j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

a disappointment or letdown; comedown.

(2) [bring you/something to your/its knees](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+knees)

to defeat or stop someone or something

-- > Severe oil shortages could bring our economy to its knees. They played a great game and brought our local basketball champs to their knees.

I'm unsure that probably one of these definitions are similar meaning to **bring you down to your knees** but I couldn't find the exact words **bring + down + knees**. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right. It is essentially saying when life has beaten you down, the brought/bring difference just has to do with a past/present tense but you have the right idiom.

Answer (score 2):

OP's cited usage is something of a [mélange](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/melange), drawing on two idiomatically common usages:

> 1: *Help me, Lord, I'm feeling low / I'm down on my knees* (= *I'm **begging** You, Lord*)
>   <sub><sup>([Bonnie Raitt - Hear Me Lord Lyrics](http://www.cowboylyrics.com/lyrics/raitt-bonnie/hear-me-lord-1701.html))</sup></sub>
>
> 2: *If a country or organization is brought to its knees, it is **almost completely destroyed***
>    <sub><sup>[(dictionary.reverso definition)](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/bring%20to%20its%20knees)</sup></sub>

There's nothing inherently *wrong* with omitting ***down*** in the first usage, or including it in the second one, but the usual forms are as given above.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine the origin may have to do with prayer. When you can't do anything about a situation you turn to God for help.